# Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002

Tags: java, yaml

Am trying to read `yaml` file contents using java code and am not able to construct java objects using java model class

Please find my `person.yaml` file

```
name: Joe
phone: 111-111-11111
address: Park Dr, Charlie Hill
```

Please find my model class

```
public class Person {

      private String name;
      private String phone;
      private String address;

}
```

Please find my service method :

```
public class PersonsService {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

         Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
          try (InputStream in = PersonsService.class
                  .getResourceAsStream("person.yaml")) {
              Person person = yaml.loadAs(in, Person.class);
              System.out.println(person);
          }

    }

}
```

Am getting the below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:com.javaproject.snakeyaml.model.Person; exception=Cannot create property=name for JavaBean=com.javaproject.snakeyaml.model.Person@77a567e1; No JavaBean properties found in com.javaproject.snakeyaml.model.Person
```

in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
    name: Joe
    ^

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @michalk - I have updated the error

Comment: create getters and setters for your `Person` class - read the error.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Reading about Java Beans (mentioned in the error) would help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error explains everything :

> Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:com.javaproject.snakeyaml.model.PersoN ... No JavaBean properties found in com.javaproject.snakeyaml.model.Person

So you have to provide getters and setters for your `Person` class so that the library will use them to set values for your `Person` class object. More about JavaBeans properties can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html).